# Get Sublime Text 2 to open file from FireFTP in new tab instead of new window on OSX

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-addon, sublimetext2

I'm fairly new to OSX. I'm using FireFTP to connect to my server and I have Sublime Text 2 as a program I can open several file types with. It opens the files, but it always creates a new window instead of using a new tab. On my Windows machine new tab was the default, but it seems to be different for some reason.

I have set "open_files_in_new_window": false in the default preferences, but this did not fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the command FireFTP uses to open a file in Sublime?

Comment: @MattDMo I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this, if you need something more specific let me know. This is the application path I have selected for it. /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was uninstalling TextWrangler, which was my default program to open these files. (I was using Right Click -> Open With... -> Sublime Text to use Sublime). Uninstalling made Sublime Text the default, and using just the Open command instead of Open With... gets me the result I was looking for. If anyone has a way to get it to work with Open With, I would still be interested in knowing how to accomplish that.